# Dados duplicados na resposta de uma consulta

Tags: php, pdo

Esse é o código :

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=locadora','root','');

$resul =  $conn->query("SELECT * FROM usuario");

echo "<pre>";
$resul = $resul->fetchAll();

?>
```

E a saída está assim :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["id_cli"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["user"]=>
    string(12) "david.santos"
    [2]=>
    string(12) "david.santos"
    ["senha"]=>
    string(60) "I82A1G"
    [3]=>
    string(60) "I82A1G"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["id_cli"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["user"]=>
    string(12) "joao.batista"
    [2]=>
    string(12) "joao.batista"
    ["senha"]=>
    string(6) "senha"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "senha"
  }
}
```

A dúvida é, porque os dados estão duplicados ? sei que se usar "fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)" o problema vai ser resolvido, mas gostaria de entender por qual motivo esta acontecendo isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só está mostrando o valor dos itens pela Key e Index de cada um, não está duplicado, ou você usa as keys ou os índices para acessar os valores